# Auto setting repeating image

Tags: theorems

I'm writing on a booklet with multiple mathematical definitions. In one of my favorite books there is a symbol next to the text at the edge when ever a definition comes up. Is there a possibility to let LaTeX automatically add an image or symbol next to the text whenever I write a definition? So I don't have to add the symbol every time.

[image]

Here is an shortened example of my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\title{Lineare Algebra 1} \author{Arjihad} \date{3. Dezember 2016}
\begin{document} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\maketitle 
\section{} 
...$N(x \cdot y) = N((ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i) = (ac-bd)^2... $ 
Definition:\\ 
... ein multiplikatives Inverses haben \\ \\ 
$k = \dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb{Z} \quad \Rightarrow k = 1 
\quad \Rightarrow a = 1 $ und... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes: define a theorem-like, unnumbered (or not) environment, which produces the label `definition` in the margin. There are packages for the proper formatting (`ntheorem,, `amstheorem`, `thmtools`…).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to ask you to give a more detailed explanation because i am really new to LaTex and not experienced at all.

Comment: Would you mind posting some *compilable* code  for what you'd like to format this way? Oh! I forgot: welcome to TeX SX!

Comment: @Arjihad if you're absolutely new to LaTeX I recommend: "J. Schlosser, Wissenschaftliches Arbeiten mit LaTeX" or "The not so short introduction to LaTeX" by Tobi Oetiker. in any case you could also edit your posting to add source code. makes it easier for the community to address your problem.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\title{Lineare Algebra 1}
\author{Arjihad}
\date{3. Dezember 2016}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 

\maketitle

\section{} 
...$N(x \cdot y) = N((ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i) = (ac-bd)^2... $
\\ \\ Definition:\\ 
... ein multiplakatives... \\ \\
$k = \dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb{Z} \quad \Rightarrow k = 1 \quad \Rightarrow a = 1 $ und...
\end{document}`

Comment: this should be fine

Answer (score 2):

Use `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {definition}% name
  {Definition}% title
  {%
    detach title,
    colback=green!70!black!25,
    colframe=green!70!black!25,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    before upper={\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] {
        \node[fill,green!70!black,rounded corners] (X) {\tcbtitle};
      }\hskip11mm}}
  }% options
  {def}% prefix
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\bfseries\color{red!50!black}}
\begin{document}

\section*{Differentiale}

\input zapf

\begin{definition}{}{label}
  Eine Folge in einer beliebigen Menge $X$ ist eine Funktion
  \[ a:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X, \quad (a_1,a_2,a_3,...) = (a_n)_{n \geq 1} = (a_n)_n = (a_n) \]
  Man spricht von Zahlenfolgen, \dots
\end{definition}

\input knuth

\end{document}
```

[image]